# Add to a collection in a loop

Tags: excel, vba, object, collections, foreach

I'm trying to add to a collection that I'll eventually throw onto a listbox.

The cases come from a two-column cell range in my workbook.

I tried using a custom object class both directly from my for each loop identifying cells of interest (commented sections), and by adding them to an array and looping through that to add them to my collection. In both cases my previous additions are overwritten by the next.

```
Private Sub formulas_Change()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim mr As Worksheet
    Dim itemID As colClass
    Set itemID = New colClass
    Dim formArr(2, 2) As Variant

    Set mr = Worksheets("Monomer Ref")

    If cols.Count <> 0 Then
        For i = 1 To cols.Count
            cols.Remove i
        Next i
    End If

    monCount = 0
    ListBox1.Clear
    i = 0

    For Each cl In Range("MonomerList")
        Select Case cl
            Case "2-Ethylhexyl acrylate"
                formArr(i, 0) = cl
                formArr(i, 1) = cl.Offset(0, 1)
                i = i + 1

'                With itemID
'                    .name = cl
'                    .tGlass = cl.Offset(0, 1)
'                End With
'                monCount = monCount + 1
'                pushCollection itemID

            Case "Methacrylic acid"
                formArr(i, 0) = cl
                formArr(i, 1) = cl.Offset(0, 1)
                i = i + 1

'                With itemID
'                    .name = cl
'                    .tGlass = cl.Offset(0, 1)
'                End With
'                monCount = monCount + 1
'                pushCollection itemID

            Case "Styrene, atactic"
                formArr(i, 0) = cl
                formArr(i, 1) = cl.Offset(0, 1)
                i = i + 1

'                With itemID
'                    .name = cl
'                    .tGlass = cl.Offset(0, 1)
'                End With
'                monCount = monCount + 1
'                pushCollection itemID

'                For Each itemID In cols
'                    MsgBox itemID.quants
'                Next itemID
        End Select
    Next cl

    For i = 0 To 2
        MsgBox i & " " & formArr(i, 0)
        With itemID
            .name = formArr(i, 0)
            .tGlass = formArr(i, 1)
        End With
        monCount = monCount + 1
        pushCollection itemID
    Next i

    Select Case formulas
        Case "-7"
            i = 0
            For Each itemID In cols
                ListBox1.AddItem
                ListBox1.List(i, 0) = itemID.name
                ListBox1.List(i, 1) = itemID.tGlass
                ListBox1.List(i, 1) = 23
                i = i + 1
            Next itemID
    End Select

End Sub


Private Sub pushCollection(itemID As colClass)
    cols.Add itemID
End Sub
```

When the code is run my collection has three objects, all "Styrene, atactic".

I know the previous objects were added, and the .Count increases by one in each case. As in, "2-Ethylhexyl acrylate" is the only object, then there are two objects that are "Methacrylic acid" and then three that are the Styrene I mentioned before.

I'm reasonably certain I can add them all directly instead of using the object class and the subroutine called for the addition, but I want to understand why this is happening for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Little hard for me to see exactly what you are doing.  But, if I want to have a group of collections, each associated with a particular key, I will usually use a Dictionary object to hold it.

First, for speed and simplicity, I would read the range to process into a VBA Array:

`myDataArr = theRangeToProcess`

And the sample code would look something like:

```
Set D = New Dictionary
For i = 1 to ubound(myDataArr,1)
    myKey = myDataArr(i,1)
    If Not D.Exists(myKey) then
        set COL = new Collection
        COL.Add myDataArr(i,2)
        D.Add key:=mykey, item:=COL
    Else
        D(myKey).Add myDataArr(i,2)
    End If
Next I
```

Then you can output the results however.